# How to create instance with pre-populated ChoiceField in form

Tags: django, generics, django-forms, django-generic-views

This is my forms.py. I want to create instance with default 'V' choice into my model. So instance was created, but with choice 'A', which i provided in model for default.

```
class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    theory_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=quests.StageTheories.THEORY_TYPE)

    class Meta:
       model = quests.StageTheories
       fields = ['title', 'youtube', 'stage']

class StageTheories(models.Model):
    THEORY_TYPE = (
        ('Q', 'Quiz'),
        ('A', 'Article'),
        ('V', 'Video'),
    )

    stage = models.ForeignKey(to=Stages, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="stage_id",verbose_name="Этап", )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=47, db_column="title", verbose_name="Заголовок теории",)
    text = models.TextField(db_column="text", verbose_name="Текст теории", null=True, blank=True,)
    youtube = models.URLField(db_column="youtube", verbose_name="Ссылка на youtube", null=True, blank=True,)
    sortOrder = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_column="sort_order", verbose_name="Порядковый номер", )
    theory_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=THEORY_TYPE, default='A')

class AddVideoView(CreateView):
    model = quests.StageTheories
    form_class = VideoForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'add_video.pug'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['stage'] = quests.Stages.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        initial['theory_type'] = 'V'
        return initial
```

Is initial value not going for form data?

Comment: in browser i see pre-populated "video" choice, but when i save, it brings "article"

Comment: i just needed to provide field 'theory_type' into class meta, instead of overriding

Answer (score 0):

Where did it inherit from?
get_initial

I think you can try to use
def **init**(...):
initial[] =
or
self.fields['name'].initial

Comment: it inherits from generic CreateView